# Discord.py on_guild_join invite command error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to get invites for every server my bot joins, but when i invite the bot in my second server i get this error in the terminal - "    invitetext = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
``

````
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Здрастии! Аз съм <@789920350796251198> и много ти благодаря, че ме покани в **{guild.name}**! Използвай .help, за да видиш списък с командите ми! Целта ми е да мога да се използвам във всеки български сървър. През времето ще се усъвършенствам и ще имам модули за музика, билети, логове и много други <:bcbwelcome:789925513748676638>",color=0x33AB8B,)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"За въпроси - .support | Версия - 0.1")
    await guild.owner.send(embed=embed)
    print(f'Joined {guild.name}')
    invitetext = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)

    server = bot.get_guild(789925449820143666)
    adminchannel = bot.server.get_channel(790193685747728414)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Server joined",color=0x33AB8B,)
    embed.add_field(name=f'Създател:', value=f'{guild.owner.mention}')
    embed.add_field(name=f'Канали:', value=(len(guild.channels)))
    embed.add_field(name=f'Роли:', value=(len(guild.roles) - 1))
    embed.add_field(name=f'Създаден на:', value=f'{guild.created_at}')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = f'{guild.icon_url}')
    embed.set_footer(text = f'{guild.name}, {guild.id}', icon_url = f'{guild.icon_url}')
    await adminchannel.send(embed=embed)
    await adminchannel.send('Invite: ', invitetext)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Finds the top guild text channel in guild

```
channel = guild.text_channels[0] #sets key to guilds id and value to top textchannel
invitetext = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
```

You could get the top channel of the guild

Comment: currently, your "channel" is not defined, it does not know which channel to create the invite for, this will find the top channel and create and invite for it